# Nesting IF statements within Do, While loops

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, do-while

I have been having an issue with a piece of code, where I want to compare a user input string to a set of strings in a column, then run a loop, which checks to see if they are identical, if not it prompts the user for another string. If they match, it goes ahead and executes the next section of the script.

I call both variables `Checktag` and `ServiceTag`: (both are Variants).

```
ServiceTag = InputBox("Please enter the laptop service tag ID")

Set TagCheck =     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B2:B1000").Find(ServiceTag, lookat:=xlWhole)

Do
If TagCheck Is Nothing Then

ServiceTag = InputBox(" User entered Service ID is not present in database, please re-enter the laptop service tag ID")

Set TagCheck = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B2:B1000").Find(ServiceTag, lookat:=xlWhole)

Else

MsgBox (" Service Tag ID recognised ")

s1.Cells(2, 3).Value = ServiceTag

End If

Loop While TagCheck Is Nothing
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

It seems like the code uninitializes TagCheck -setting it to nothing- if it has not been matched the the ServiceTag Value.

I have another sub which does a similar job, but then goes ahead and writes to a specific cell after performing another cell/user comparison:

```
 Set rngX = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B2:B1000").Find(ServiceTag, lookat:=xlWhole)

Set TagCheckA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C10000").Find(ServiceTag, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not TagCheckA Is Nothing Then

RowZ = Range(TagCheckA.Address).Row

DateReadA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowZ, 7).Value

End If

If TagCheck = TagCheckA And DateRead = DateReadA Then

    If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
         RowX = Range(rngX.Address).Row
         s5.Cells(RowX, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         s5.Cells(RowX, 3).Value = " Checked IN "
         s5.Cells(RowX, 4).Value = myDate

      End If

s1.Cells(RowZ, 8).Value = myDate

MsgBox ("The Laptop has been Sucessfully Signed IN")
```

In this case I want a cell to be edited and filled green when the matches are satisfied. However, it always skips that section of code and jumps straight to the final message-box. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see an efficient exit from your coded loop. A user should be able to exit by simply clicking <kbd>Cancel</kbd>.

```
Sub st()
    Dim ServiceTag As String, s1 As Worksheet

    Set s1 = Worksheets("Service Tags")

    ServiceTag = InputBox("Please enter the laptop service tag ID")

    Do While CBool(Len(ServiceTag))

        If CBool(Application.CountIf(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B2:B1000"), ServiceTag)) Then
            MsgBox (" Service Tag ID recognised ")
            'need to have some way to increment the receiving cell - see commented line
            s1.Cells(2, 3).Value = ServiceTag
            's1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).offxet(1, 0) = ServiceTag
        End If

        ServiceTag = InputBox("Please enter the laptop service tag ID")
    Loop
End Sub
```

I've never been a fan of using the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) and comparing the result to `Nothing`. Bringing in a worksheet function like [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) will simply resolve to zero (e.g. *False*) or anything other than zero (e.g. *True*).

Comment: Thank you, i will Give COUNTIF and CBool a try, This a part of the first piece of VBA code I have ever made, so I am largely unaware of most of its methods. I do like it so far though. When you say that there is no effeciant way of exiting, do you mean exit the whole sub, or just exit from the dialog box in the do while loop? (or does one trigger the exit of the whole thing?)

Comment: tbh, the `CBool(...)` is largely used as a reminder that the function's returned value is being evaluated as a boolean. In reality, a zero is false and anything that is not zero is true.